# Possible to create a function to generically set the member of the struct passed in?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to have a generic function such that it sets the respective member of the struct being passed in?

I think a template would be needed which could take in the object being used along with the data to be set but how would you go about putting everything together? i.e figuring out how to pass a member of any struct that could be modified by the function

```cpp
struct A {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct B {
    double z;
};

template<typename T>
void change(T t, void *x)
{

}

int main(void) 
{
   A a;
   B b;
   int valueA = 5;
   double valueB = 10.3;
   change<A>(a, &valueA);   // I want change() to: a.x = 5;
   change<B>(b, &valueB);   // I want change() to: b.z = 10.3;
}
```

Comment: `A` has `x` and `y`, what indicates that `x` should be written to? What indicates that `z` should be written to for `B`?

Comment: that's just an example. I'm trying to figure out if it's even possible to be able to set any struct member through a generic function

Comment: Considering that `A` has more than one member, something has to be added to indicate which member should be written to. You need to elaborate what you want to happen

Comment: well...you can see i'm passing `a` as the first argument indicating which member needs to be modified

Comment: I'm voting to close because the question is unclear. How does even `change<A>(a, &valueA);` mean that you want to change `a.x` and not `a.y`? What would you write if you wanted it to change `a.y`?

Comment: How does `a` indicate one of `x` or `y`?

Comment: my apologies. that's the part I'm trying to figure out. This code isn't fully functional but I put together as much based on my understanding. there are missing pieces

Comment: @Jazzy, it's not about missing pieces. It's about understanding yourself what you want to ask. Please, answer the question: how do you write down a line to change `a.y` to `5`?

Comment: Sorry but that's exactly what this question is about: writing a generic function that takes in a struct along with the member that needs to be modified with the value being passed in. That's what I'm trying to figure out. The comments include what's the intended behavior

Comment: Then at the very least the function needs 3 arguments: an instance of the struct, an indication of what member to change, and the value to set the member to

Comment: I didn't write the *wrong* code to avoid any confusion hence left that part. Three arguments make sense but then the members could be of different type...so I can't really hardcode, say, `int` right

Comment: @Jazzy,  You write the code `change<A>(a, &valueA);` and say `I want change() to: a.x = 5`. Now I'm asking: in the imaginary working code, what would you write to indicate that you want to do `a.y = 5`?

Comment: pass the member of the struct that needs to be modified

Comment: @Jazzy, _Hello Enlico, the line `change<A>(a, &valueA);` results in `a.x = 5;`, whereas the line `FILL THIS` results in `a.y = 5;`_. Can you please fill it in?

Comment: looks like you haven't understood the question, sorry. `change<A>(a, &valueA);` is just an example that I wrote that doesn't have any members as an argument. Why? I didn't explicitly add because I didn't know how would the function header itself look like given I don't want to hardcode the type...the whole point i'm getting at is to have a function that maybe takes 3 arguments, and sets the member to the value passed in

Comment: After thinking about it some it actually makes more sense to just pass the member and a value without passing the struct

Comment: @Jazzy, give a look at my answer. If it doesn't answer, please update your question to explain why.

Comment: @Jazzy, as implied by JHBonarius' comment, what's wrong with doing just `a.x = valueA;` instead of `change<A>(a, &valueA);`? What shiny bright advantage does the second syntax offer to you? Please, consider reading [this brief page](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you're really trying to do, and ***I'm sure that the whole question is just an expression of the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)***, but here are some ideas based on the current state of the question and the comments.

First, given the code

```cpp
template<typename T>
void change(T t, void *x)
{

}
```

the lines

```cpp
   change<A>(a, &valueA);   // I want change() to: a.x = 5;
   change<B>(b, &valueB);   // I want change() to: b.z = 10.3;
```

will not change anything, because `change` is taking its first argument by value, so it will modify the copies of `a` and `b`, not them. To actually modify the arugments, you'd need to take by `T&`.

Furthermore, if your intention is to modify the input regardless of it being of type `A` or  `B`, why don't you  rely on function overloading?

```cpp
void change(A& a, void *x)
{
    a.x = *static_cast<decltype(A::x)*>(x);
}
void change(B& b, void *x)
{
    b.z = *static_cast<decltype(B::z)*>(x);
}
```

Comment: That would need a cast, right? Can't dereference a void pointer

Comment: @JHBonarius, never used `void` pointers, sorry. I guess the code is now correct.

Comment: Never? Wow, you missed out on a whole realm of UB .

Comment: I don't know how much of the STL uses `void*`s. Maybe `std::function` does? But I don't know, don't care, and I think that's a good thing. Those `void*`s just scare me...

Comment: Inherited from C. They're just type erased object pointers. They still have specific use cases, but in modern C++ the std library handles most of them for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are ok with directly passing the member you want to change rather than just an instance of the struct then you can just use a function like this to set the member:

```
template <typename T>
void change(T& m, T&& v) { m = v; }
```

The purpose of `T& m` is to pass the member by reference so it actually gets set (your example passes by value). The purpose of `T&& v` is to avoid copying the value as an argument

Below an example for some different types of members:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A {
    int x;
    double y;
    std::string z;

    void print() const {
        std::cout << "x: " << x << ", y: " << y << ", z: " << z << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
void change(T& m, T&& v) { m = v; }

int main() {
    A a;
    a.x = 1;
    a.y = 0.5;
    a.z = "abc";

    a.print();
    change(a.x, 42);
    change(a.y, 3.14);
    change(a.z, std::string("xyz"));
    a.print();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
x: 1, y: 0.5, z: abc
x: 42, y: 3.14, z: xyz
```

Comment: Haha, yes, but this seems reinventing the assignment operator. If I'd ever find this in production code, I'd have a very serious conversation with the one who committed it.

Comment: @JHBonarius, I agree but if this is not what the OP wants then I don't know what it is

Comment: @asimes it's more about the correctness of the code ;) your code does work but looks like that's what an assignment operator would do except I don't want to return anything. I'll test that on my end